# write a HTML form to webpage using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm writing a javascript library and I need to make a javascript function which you can call to create a form (scheduler) on your webpage.

this is the html code of the form:

```
    <form>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr><td id="schedulename" colspan="10">Time Schedule</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50">hours</td>
        <td></td>
        <td width="50">minutes</td>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tue</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thu</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>Sun</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50"><input type="text" id="hours" maxlength="2" size="1"></td> 
        <td width="2"> : </td> 
        <td width="50"><input type="text" id="minutes" maxlength="2" size="1"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="mon"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="tue"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="wed"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="thu"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="fri"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="sat"></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="sun"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td colspan="10"> <input type="button" id="setbutton" value="Set schedule"></td>
    </table>
    </form>
```

my idea of the result is that a user only needs to create a div in his webpage, then in the javascript, call my function with the right parameters which in turn shows my predefined form. But I also need to add some functionality to the 'setbutton' it needs to write the data to an adres in my PLC (programmable logic controller)

what I want the function call to look like: showScheduler(id, adres);
id is the id of the division and adres is the adres in my programmable logic controller I need to write to.

What is the best way to write the form to my webpage from within a javascript function?

I hope u guys can understand but i'll gladly give you more explanation if needed.

Comment: Note: when you create multiple forms dont use `id`, but `class` instead (inside the forms) ;-)

Comment: @joelharkes so if i use my function to create multiple forms on the same page this will not work? I need to change all the id's of the inputs to a class identifier? I don't really understand, can u explain more please? :)

Comment: `id`s are used to identify a single dom element eg, a single input field or a single div. so when you create multiple froms you get multiple ids of eg. `schedulename`. when u use more javascript (or jquery) to get for example al the schedulenames this wil start getting buggy (because javascript most likely will only get the first one)

Comment: @joelharkes so for every element in my form, i need to use 'class' instead of 'id' right? but then how do I access the value of the input boxes and the checkboxes? I need to access those values from my javascript code so i can determine which hour and min has been entered and which day has been selected, hope u understand this :p

Comment: in javascript: `getElementsByClassName('classname')` although i would suggest using jquery, its way easier: `$('.classname')` (note, jquery uses the css notation, and thus easier readable)

Comment: @joelharkes so for example: this is what will be written to the div in the webpage by my function : `<td class="schedulename" colspan="10">Time Schedule</td>`
and if I call my function twice (for example I want 2 schedules) won't both td's have the same classname? because it is written like that in the function? how do I know which td belongs to which table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<div id="placeholder">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function createForm(divId) {
        var formHtml = "<form><table border='1' cellpadding='5'>...</table></form>";
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = formHtml;
    }
</script>
```

And call for example `createForm("placeholder")` when you want.

Comment: thx man, but 1 more question, can I bind functionality to the button after it has been written to the HTML page?
example: 
`function createForm(divId) {
     var formHtml = "<form><table border='1' cellpadding='5'>...</table></form>";
      document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = formHtml;
      $(#setbutton).click( function() {
 sendValues();
      });

    }`

Comment: Yes, for example, you can do this, after changing the innerHTML of divId: document.getElementById("setbutton").onclick = function(event){alert('test');};

Comment: ok I know what I need to know, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are specifically wanting the user to **ONLY** have their html and a `<script>` tag that loads in your js file. You will need to require a specific `id` or custom css class to use as a selector. Then the html part for the user would simply look like:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<div id="customID"></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your javascript file, you need to create your function to write in the content, and tie that function to an execution on `window.load()`. Something like:

```
$( //note, this causes execution when the dom is loaded, using jQuery's .ready()
   function(){ showScheduler("customID"); }
);

function showScheduler(id)
{
    var contents = '<form><table border="1" cellpadding="5">...</table></form>'; //the ... needs to have the rest of your html with no single quotes anywhere inside
    $("#"+id).html(contents);
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for regarding the `adress` part, but you could easily extend the `showScheduler()` function to include a second parameter for the `adress` value, and then stick that into the middle of the rest of the `contents` value. Something like:

```
function showScheduler(id, adress)
{
    var contents = '<form><table border="1" cellpadding="5">...' + adress + '...</table></form>'; //the ... needs to have the rest of your html with no single quotes anywhere inside
    $("#"+id).html(contents);
}
```

And further, if you prefer to have the user call the function from their page, you can skip the part about tying this to this to the dom's execution (i.e. remove the `$( function(){ showScheduler("customID"); } );` part completely